# Creating OU in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell-ise

I wrote a script based on the guidelines given to me, however I am getting some errors.
This is the script I have:

```
 $aryText = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\stepbystep.txt"

 foreach ($aryElement in $aryText)
 {
   $strClass = "organizationalUnit"
   $strOUName = $aryElement
   $objADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://dc=nwtraders,dc=msft"
   $objOU = $objADSI.Create($strCLass, $strOUName)
   $objOU.SetInfo()
 }
```

The error I get are "The Following exception occurred while retrieving member "Create": "A referral was returned from the server." This happens at the $objOU = $objADSI.Create($strCLass, $strOUName) line

I also get a second error, probably because of the first error stating "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression". And this happens at $objOU.SetInfo(). Any help on how to fix these errors or what steps I should take next would be greatly appreciated.